# Program opens the same named pipe and writes to it many times with C

Tags: c, linux, pipe, named-pipes

I created two programs, which will communicate via named pipe, one will be reading from it and another one will be writing to it. It works pretty fine now, except for the fact, that it opens and writes to the same fifo exactly 3 times. It's my first time with C and pipes, and I don't understand why is this writing three times. Can you see why is this writing three times?

**writing.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 512
#define err(mess) { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); }


void writing(char *s)
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t n;

    char buf[BUFFSIZE];

    printf("writing to %s\n",s);
    if ( (fd = open(s, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
        err("open")

    while( (n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof buf -1) ) > 0) {
    buf[n-1] = '\0';

        printf("Received: %s\n", buf);

        if ( write(fd, buf, n) != n) { 
            err("write");
        }
    if(strcmp(buf,"END")==0){
           printf("%s","exit");
       break;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
}

char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);//+1 for the zero-terminator
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

int file_stat(char *argv){

           int isfifo = 0;
       struct stat sb;

           printf("%s",argv);

           if (stat(argv, &sb) == -1) {
               perror("stat");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           printf("File type:                ");

           if (sb.st_mode & S_IFMT == S_IFIFO) {
            printf("FIFO/pipe\n");
        isfifo = 1;

           }

           printf("Ownership:                UID=%ld   GID=%ld\n",
                   (long) sb.st_uid, (long) sb.st_gid);


           //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       return isfifo;



}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // READ ALL FILES IN DIRECTORY
    if (argc != 2) {
               fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s /<pathname>/\n", argv[0]);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    if ((d = opendir (argv[1])) != NULL) {
        /* print all the files and directories within directory */
        while ((dir = readdir (d)) != NULL) {
                printf ("%s\n", dir->d_name);
            char* s = concat(argv[1], dir->d_name);
            if (file_stat(s) == 1) {
                writing(s);
            }
            else {
                mkfifo("fifo_x", 0666);
                writing("fifo_x");      
            }
            free(s);
        }
        closedir (d);
    }
    else {
        /* could not open directory */
        perror ("error: ");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

reading file is the same except for "reading" function and call to `reading()`
**reading**

```
void reading(char *s)
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    printf("%s",s);

    if ( (fd = open(s, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        err("open");


    while( (n = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1) ) > 0) {

    buf[n-1] = '\0';
    if(strcmp(buf,"END")==0){
           printf("%s\n", "exit");
       break;
        }
    buf[n-1] = '\n';
    if ( write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n) { 
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

**the output**

```
/home/..File type:                Ownership:                UID=0   GID=0
writing to fifo_x
END
Received: END
exitola
/home/olaFile type:                Ownership:                UID=1001   GID=1001
writing to fifo_x
END
Received: END
exit.
/home/.File type:                Ownership:                UID=0   GID=0
writing to fifo_x
END
Received: END
exit
```

Comment: Whenever you run a program, it writes three time. Why it is writing three time is it your question ?

Comment: Yes. I'm asking why my programs open the same pipe and write to the same pipe multiple times (exactly three).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three files in the directory with whose pathname you called your program. All three files are not fifo's so for each you write to `fifo_x`.

The file names are

```
    .
    ..
    olaFile
```

Maybe you should explicitly exclude the files

```
    .
    ..
```

which happen to be in every directory in linux and represent the current directory `.` and the parent directory `..`.